# How to work with flt & hdr files

Tags: raster, r

I have been working on a vector-based spatial analysis in R using shapefiles.
I wish to use some environmental data that is downloadable, however it is only available in raster format (FLT & HDR files).

I have no experience of working with rasters. How can I work with these files and combine with the shapefiles for further analysis?

Comment: The files I want to use are here:
http://erc.epa.ie/safer/iso19115/displayAllAttachments.jsp?isoID=7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article explaining how to use the flt/hdr files in R. I see GDAL will convert these files. ArcMap 10.1 opened the flt.hdr files too. [FLT](http://geospaced.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/reading-afripop-data.html)

Comment: Thanks! I can't get the GDALinfo command to work but was able to read data in and plot it using raster. Thank you it is a start!

Answer (score 1):

Using the R package "raster",you can read the file of ENVI image,include "bil" "hdr", such as:

```
require(raster)
a <- raster("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/et180415/et180415.bil")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! This is so far a better answer than the accepted one - could you click 'edit' and add some more information about how this process works?